# Instagram Business Discovery API Invalid OAuth access token

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, facebook-access-token, instagram-graph-api

I am trying to use Instagram Business Discovery API to get followers count of my page.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/business-discovery

Here is my code.
[https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/XXXX?fields=business_discovery.username(XXXX){followers_count}&access_token=XXXXXX](https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/XXXX?fields=business_discovery.username(XXXX)%7Bfollowers_count%7D&access_token=XXXXXX)

Note : I have mentioned my insta page name & access token as XXXX

But i am getting error like this

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Invalid OAuth access token.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 190,
      "fbtrace_id": "A1vFKk5CZd0xerJsnpaAk1_"
   }
}
```

This is the article followed to generate access token.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/getting-started/

If i check the access toke in [Access Token Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken), its showing as valid true. This is how it shows.

[image]

Is there anything missed? Please help!

Comment: According to that screenshot the token doesn't have the permissions required for using Basic Display API, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/overview#permissions

Comment: instagram_graph_user_profile this permission you mean? @AndrewL

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the required permissions for user business discovery api end point , following is the list of permission which would be needed to perform business discovery search

1. instagram_basic
2. instagram_manage_insights
3. pages_read_engagement or pages_show_list

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user/business_discovery

You can obtain this permission through review process , further you can use developement version of your facebook app which doesn't require to obtain permission through review process but there are limitation on number of api hits.